# Storing Data as XML BLOB

Tags: sql, xml, blob

At the moment the team i am working with is looking into the possibility of storing data which is entered by users from a series of input wizard screens as an XML blob in the database. the main reason for this being that i would like to write the input wizard as a component which can be brought into a number of systems without having to bring with it a large table structure.

To try to clarify if the wizard has 100 input fields (for example) then if i go with the normal relational db structure then their will be a 1 to 1 relationship so will have 100 columns in database. So to get this working in another system will have to bring the tables,strore procedures etc into the new system.

I have a number of reservations about this but i would like peoples opinions??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If those inputted fields don't need to be updated or to be used for later calculation or computation some values using xml or JSON is a smart choice.
so for your scenario seems like its a perfect solution